# Double request permission when using Oauth2 Google

Tags: javascript, google-oauth, google-analytics-api, google-signin, google-api-js-client

I have issue when using "client:auth2:analytics" (Google Authenticate & Analytics). After i choose a account to verify, a dialog other will appear over authenticate dialog to request user allow some permission of app (look at the picture below), how way can auto allow all permisison ?

- Request user confirm permissions.

[image]

- Then, still request user confirm permissions.

[image]

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.manage.users
```

```
this.onLoad = function () {
  const thiss = this;
  window.onload = function () {
     gapi.load('client:auth2:analytics', function () {
      gapi.client.init({
       'apiKey': thiss.config.apiKey,
       'clientId': thiss.config.clientId,
       'scope': thiss.config.scope,
      }).then(function () {

       thiss.handleBtnAuthClickStateful('reset');

       thiss.GoogleAuth = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();

       thiss.onAuthClick();
      });
     });
  }
}
```

```
this.onAuthClick = function () {
   const thiss = this;
   $(document).on('click', `#${thiss.html.btnAuthAnalytics}`, function () {
     thiss.handleOnAuthClick();
   });
};
```

```
this.handleOnAuthClick = function () {
  const thiss = this;

  if (!thiss.handleValidate()) {
    thiss.handleResetAuth();

    thiss.GoogleAuth.signIn().then(function () {
      if (thiss.GoogleAuth.isSignedIn.get()) {
        thiss.handleAfterSignIn();
      }
    });
  }
};
```

```
this.handleResetAuth = function () {
  const thiss = this;

  thiss.GoogleAuth.signOut();
  thiss.GoogleAuth.disconnect();
};
```

Comment: Only the user can authorize permissions. You cannot auto authorize permission grants. There is an exception with Domain-Wide Delegation (G Suite), but I have not used these tokens (created from a service account) for Google Analytics.

Comment: Yes, but now, when user click authenticate button they must confirm permission at two screen, i think just confirm at one screen that's better for user,  you can check  my update in topic again.

Comment: Google is making the user confirm in two steps. This is good. There is nothing that I am aware that you can do. I prefer a little inconvenience to get better security. I expect Google to get tighter with authorization grants, not looser. You can of course open a feature request.

Comment: Thanks you so much :D.

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to the un-verified domain name.

All you need to Verify your Domain name and Provide the App name and website address in Oauth console

- Goto https://console.developers.google.com/
- Domain Verification
- Add Domain
- Follow the steps (use one of the multiple methods provided by google)